# How to merge 2 object from different list in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following 2 list of *Item* objects in c#:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Orders { get; set; }
}

List<Item> items1 = new List<Item>() { 
      new Item() { Id = 1, Code = 23, Orders = new List<string>() { "A", "B" }},
      new Item() { Id = 2, Code = 24, Orders = new List<string>() { "C", "D" }}
};

List<Item> items2 = new List<Item>() { 
      new Item() { Id = 1, Code = 23, Orders = new List<string>() { "E", "F" }},
      new Item() { Id = 2, Code = 24, Orders = new List<string>() { "G", "H" }}
};
```

I want to merge the Item objects from both lists whose Id and code is same, so the output of above 2 list should be single list with the following entries:

```
{ 
  new Item() { Id = 1, Code = 23, Orders = new List<string>() { 'A', 'B', 'E', 'F' },
  new Item() { Id = 2, Code = 24, Orders = new List<string>() { 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H' }
};
```

How can i do this in c# using linq ?

Comment: @Servy not duplicate, in earlier question there was only 1 list and in this question the lists are 2

Comment: Then your question becomes how to combine the items from two different lists into a single list, and *that* is answered by your earlier question.  I'm sure you can figure out how to create a new list/enumerable with the items from both collections, and if not, Google can tell you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both list and then `Union` their `Orders` like:

```
List<Item> combined = (from t in items1
                       join r in items2 on new { t.Id, t.Code } equals new { r.Id, r.Code }
                       select new Item
                       {
                           Id = t.Id,
                           Code = t.Code,
                           Orders = t.Orders.Union(r.Orders).ToList()

                       }).ToList();
```

You will get:

[image]

If you need your `Orders` to be concatenated then you can replace `Union` with `Concat`. So if your order contains "A", "B" and "A", "F", then with concat you will get `"A","B,"A","F"` and with `Union` you will get `"A", "B", "F"`

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from x in items1
             join y in items2 on x.Id equals y.Id
             select new Item
                {
                    Id = x.Id, 
                    Code = x.Code,
                    Orders = x.Orders.Concat(y.Orders).ToList()
                };
```

Comment: Is the same thing is possible with linq syntax ?

Comment: @user1740381 LINQ is not a syntax, it is a collection of methods in the `System.Linq` namespace.  Perhaps you're referring to "method syntax", in which the answer is yes, all query syntax expressions are translated into method syntax under the hood; you can always do this translation yourself if you want.