# Merge equal items with multiple lists but different length

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists.

They are different in length but same type.

I want that an Item from List2 replaces an equal item in List1.

```
var item1 = new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Test1" };
var item2 = new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Test2" };
var item3 = new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Test3" };
var item4 = new Item { Id = 4, Name = "Test4" };
var item5 = new Item { Id = 5, Name = "Test5" };

var list1 = new List<Item> { item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 };
var list2 = new List<Item> { new Item { Id = 1, Name = "NewValue" } };
```

As a result I expect a list with 5 items where the item with Id = 1 has a value "NewValue".

How can I do that preferable with linq.

**UPDATE**

I extend my question:

How can the replacement of the replaced Item happen without copying all properties manually. Just imagine I have 100 properties...

Comment: do a google search and you will see tons of results / examples ..here is one for you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819619/how-to-merge-2-object-from-different-list-in-c

Comment: I updated my question. And I used google but I could not find your link - which does only partly help me -

Comment: what do you mean you can't find this link it's right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819619/how-to-merge-2-object-from-different-list-in-c

Comment: Would you need any property values from the original list?

Comment: I meant I did not find your link in google. That means the google result depend on the keywords you use.

Comment: I did a simple google search and this is what  I typed `C# stackoverflow Merge items from 2 different List<T>`

Comment: @YacoubMassad No. I want a full replacement.

Comment: Do you have to keep the same order?

Comment: I searched for: merge multiple lists. You see...

Comment: @YacoubMassad No , the order of the items doesnt matter.

Comment: Use Enumerable.Union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

First define an equality comparer that depends only on the `Id` property of the `Item` class like this:

```
public class IdBasedItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can take items `list1` that don't have corresponding items in `list2` using the `Except` method and then you can concatenate that with `list2` using the `Concat` method like this:

```
var result = list1.Except(list2, new IdBasedItemEqualityComparer()).Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Notice how I use the `IdBasedItemEqualityComparer` with the `Except` method, so that comparison is based only on `Id`.

Comment: Ok you do first a RemoveDuplicateItems, then Add all items.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head this is one solution

```
var list3 = new List<Item>();    

foreach (var item in list1)   
   list3.Add(list2.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == item.Id) ?? item);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think LEFT OUTER JOIN in Linq will be able to merge 2 lists regardless of number of properties(columns) like this:

```
    List<Item> newItems =
        (from l1 in list1
         join l2 in list2 on l1.Id equals l2.Id into l12
         from l2 in l12.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { Item = (l2 == null) ? l1 : l2 }).Select(r => r.Item).ToList();
```